# Parameterized test don't work with GuiceExtension

Tags: java, junit

Hi everyone!

```
    @ExtendWith({
            DbFixtureExtension.class,
            GuiceExtension.class
    })
    @IncludeModule({
            ApiModule.class,
            WebModule.class,
            DataModule.class,
            JsonHelperModule.class,
            DatabaseModule.class
    })
public class Simple {
    @Inject
    private WebSteps WebSteps;

    @Inject
    private DbSteps dbSteps;

    public void func(String string) {
        final Phone phone = Phone.of(Phone.RU_PREFIX, string);

        WebSteps.openLoginPage()
                .sendCodeForPhone(phone)
                .checkCode(dbSteps.getAuthCode(phone));
    }
   
    @ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(strings = {"1", "2", "3"})
    public void test(String numb) {
        func(numb);
    }
}
```

Console show me this exception

```
org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: Discovered multiple competing ParameterResolvers for parameter [java.lang.String numb] in method [public void ru.Simple.test(java.lang.String)]: name.falgout.jeffrey.testing.junit.guice.GuiceExtension@1b46d2d8, org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTestParameterResolver@56cf348d
```

I think this code is not work because GuiceExtension alredy implements ParameterResolever. How i can fix this? I proboval implements ParameterResolver interface in my Simple test class, but it not work for me.

Comment: Where does the `GuiceExtension` comes from?  It seems it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: @Davide, https://github.com/JeffreyFalgout/junit5-extensions/tree/master/guice-extension